# Get DataContext from Sub Page in a Split View Frame

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a MainWindow, with a command bar. Inside this, I have a classic hamburger menu with a Splitview Frame. I open another page Inside the Splitview Frame when I click on the hamburger buttons.

However, I want to get the page which is opened right now in my Splitview Frame and the data from my gridview when I click on the button in my command bar. (see the picture)
[image]

I tried this command from the splitview Frame but I didn't achieve any success:

```
var type = SplitViewFrame.CurrentSourcePageType;
```

It shows me the type of the page which is nice, but I don't know how to work with it.

Comment: 1) When you load your Page inside frame, Make sure you save the instance of the frame that you pass to the frame. 2) Make the data context of your page that you pass to the frame public by making that as either a public property or dependancy property. Now you should be able to access the data context from your main splitview page.

Comment: From outside the `SplitView`, you could use the [`Content` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.splitview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I achived my result like this:

First I get the current shown page like this:

```
Page page = SplitViewFrame.Content as Page;
```

Then I find my GridView Control by name(I know it is hardcoded but it works in my case):

```
GridView gridview = page.FindName("GridViewAllgemein") as GridView;
```

And then I read the datasource from the GridView like this:

```
List<SQLService.Ausstattung> ausstattungen = (List<SQLService.Ausstattung>) gridview.ItemsSource;
```